# Getting An Error Message from Javascript to Appear Next to An HTML/JSP Input Using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

OK, so I have an input form very basic CRUD sort of thing.  I have my validation occurring through Javascript, and when an error occurs the error message appears underneath the input field.  I have the CSS up and running, and the text that was previously black is now red.  I have tried floats, adjusting the margin, displaying inline, etc. but cannot find any sort of methodology.

The code is on another computer, but what basically occurs is...

The JS checks for a span value in the HTML if it's not there it creates it, if it creates it the error message is thrown, and it's properties are set by the CSS.

Here is some of the HTML

```
<label for="fName">First Name:</label>

         <form:input type="text" name="fName" id="fName" path="fName"/>

         <div id = "fName.errorField"><font color="red"><form:errors     cssClass= "error"  path="fName" /></font></div><br />
```

A piece of the js

```
      if(document.getElementById('fName.errors') == null){

              newSpan.id = "fname.errors";

                 newSpan.className = "error";

                document.getElementById('fname.errorField').appendChild(newSpan);

              newSpan = document.createElement("span");

       }

 function validateFName() {

    var alphaChar =  /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;

    var nameFChek = document.input.fName.value;



    if (nameFChek == ""){

            document.getElementById("fName.errors").innerHTML = "This field is blank (fname)";

           return false;

    }
```

and the CSS I currently have

```
form { width: 800px;}

   label { float: left; width: 150px;}

   input[type=text] { float: left; width: 250px;}

   .clear { clear:both; height: 0; line-height: 0;}

   .floatright { float: right;}
```

Comment: Please attach your html, js and css, preferably using http://jsfiddle.net. That would make it easier for us to see your problem.

Comment: I added the code, I couldn't get it all into a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see you are actually creating a new span and adding it to the DOM in pure javascript. I don't know how big your project is already, but I'd really recommend you use some tool for validation like jquery validate: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

And even if you already have a lot of code, I still recommend you to use a plug-in for any future development.

You can also take a look at http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/, maybe you'll wanna peek into the demo's CSS.

Without a working jsfiddle it's hard to know what's wrong with your code.

Comment: Apparently the CSS is imported in this demo.  There really is nothing wrong in my code. Everything functions as it should.  Here's the thing

Label>Input they are next to each other they both float left in the CSS, and I think you can see that above.

the error message appears something like this

Label>Input
Error
If I float right It stays below the label and input, but goes all the way right, it I float left it just stays in it's present position.  A JS Fiddle isn't going to really help with that.  I need help figuring out not the JS, just go reposition the error message.